# How to add Loader for after placing a order in magento 2

Tags: checkout, frontend, magento2.3.2, loader

I am using an online payment method Paypal on my site.

I can place the order successfully using the Paypal payment method.

But after placing the order, it takes some time to redirect to the success page.

Until then I need to show loader.

How do I add loader in the checkout page

Answer (score 0):

To show the spinner add this JS when you submit the payment:

```
$('body').loader('show');
```

I doubt you'll need to remove it as the page will change to the success page but if you do need to remove it use this JS:

```
$('body').loader('hide');
```